# Why does my tablesorter keep caching my old rows?

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter to sort a grid on one of my pages.  I'm making an AJAX call every 10 seconds for updated stock information, and updating my grid accordingly.  That much is working, but I can't get my sort options to cache properly.  Rather, I seem to have cached the sorting, but when I do, tablesorter also caches my previous rows, and displays them along with the new, sorted set of rows.

Example, my initial grid has 10 rows of data.  I sort on the second column.  After 10 seconds, a new set of 10 rows come in, but my initial 10 rows still show up, even though I've emptied them out.  I've researched all over, and I can't seem to find the answer for this.

If I don't sort at all, and I don't call the trigger for "sorton", I get my 10 rows as desired, but the rows aren't sorted of course.  If I call that trigger for "sorton", my data gets sorted, but I get 10 new rows every time the function gets called (20 rows total, then 30 rows total, etc).

Here is my code from inside my AJAX call:

```
if (myResult.Data.length > 0) {
    $.each(myResult.Data, function() {
        myRows += "<tr><td>" + this.column1 + "</td><td>" + this.column2 + "</td></tr>";
    });
    $("#myTBody").empty();
    //    $("#myTBody").append(myRows);    //tried this first
    //    $("#myTable").trigger("update"); // combined with this
    $("#myTBody").append(myRrows).trigger("update");
    var sorting = $("#myTable")[0].config.sortList;
    $("#myTable").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, that seems to be an issue with the original tablesorter ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/208/)).

Sorry I don't remember the reason why the cache doesn't get cleared during the update; but this issue doesn't happen in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/209/)).

Comment: I just take a look at the original tablesorter JS code. In the update function, it calls `cache = buildCache(me);` in a setTimeout function which will be executed after 1ms. This causes the sorton to use the cache before the cache is updated. Thus, if I trigger my `sorton` after 100ms I triggered the `update`, for example, then I can get the sorting done without additional rows appending to the result.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Same caching problem (caused by update --> sorton) in your fork.

Answer (score 9):

Although this post is old, just in case there is someone like me who is looking for fixes to the original tablesorter, I fix the issue by having `sorton` triggered in the following "delayed" way.

```
$("#myTBody").append(myRrows).trigger("update");
var sorting = $("#myTable")[0].config.sortList;
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#myTable").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
}, 100);
```

The reason of doing so is because the `update` function in the original tablesorter doesn't update the cache immediately. It updates it 1ms after the `update` method is called. So, `sorton` can't get the updated cache immediately. This is what I conclude after reading the original JS code, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/692/

Comment: this worked for me too.. The answer below from Saran did not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution w/o using timeout:

```
$("#myTBody")
  .append(myRrows);
$("#myTable")
  .trigger("update")
  .trigger("sorton", [$("#myTable")[0].config.sortList])
  .trigger("appendCache");
```

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013571/451962

Answer (score 0):

Old post but recently got into this issue,
for me this worked

```
$("#myTable")[0].config.cache = null;
$("#myTable").trigger("sorton");
```

It just keep the cache either I was not able to find any reasonable flag to avoid it so I set it null